# Nullpointer exception - FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have received a nullpointer exception error in my fragmentactivity.

Below is the log cat:

```
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at com.dooba.beta.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-04 06:29:51.550: E/AndroidRuntime(19286):    ... 11 more
```

I believe the error occurs within these lines:

```
 mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
         .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         mOptionMenu));
```

Below is the entire activity code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private String[] mOptionMenu;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mTitleSection;
    private CharSequence mTitleApp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mOptionMenu = new String[] { "Opción 1", "Opción 2", "Opción 3" };
         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)
         findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_drawer);
         mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
         .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
         mOptionMenu));

         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {

         Fragment fragment = null;

         switch (position) {
         case 0:
         fragment = new FirstFragment();
         break;
         case 1:
         fragment = new SecondFragment();
         break;
         case 2:
         fragment = new ThirdFragment();
         break;
         }

         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

         mTitleSection = mOptionMenu[position];
         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);

         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);
         }
         });
         mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true);
         mTitleSection = getTitle();
         mTitleApp = getTitle();

         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
         R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
         R.string.drawer_close) {

         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }

         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
         getActionBar().setTitle(mTitleSection);
         ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.this);
         }
         };

         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ;
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

If any clarification is needed, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of getActionBar() and mDrawerList ?

Comment: The easiest way for you to figure out what is `null` is to separate all methods and variables of that error line into their own variables and then put a breakpoint there and do step-debugging

Comment: thanks for your response. What do you exactly mean by value of getActionBar?

Comment: Well, as @StackFlowed said, mainly you need to check which one of these two: `mDrawerList`, `getActionBar()` gives you a `null` value

Comment: I have come to conlusion that its getActionBar(), with suggestion have replaced getActionBar().getThemedContext(), with MainActivity.this, but in doing so have encounntered a nullpoint exception error at the following line:          getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Look at the answer by Lukas. getActionBar() is not supported in the API level that you are building to. So it will always return null. You need to either increase your API level or use a supported API call within the API level that you are targeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
getActionBar().getThemedContext()
```

use `this`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Upon applying it, I receive the following nullpoint exception error at the following line: 
         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that depends on the theme you use. If your app theme doesn't have action bar you get null returned. If your theme has actioj bar then let your activity extend ActionBarActivity: it's a subclass of FragmentActivity so you should have no problem, instead of call getActionBar() you have to call getSupportActionBar() because FragmentActivity anf ActionBarActivity are part of support library. I repeat I'm not 100% sure about that, let me know if you found a solution

Comment: this is the theme used for the application or activity @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"> and this is the theme for the actionbar style used @style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar

Comment: Then try the solution with ActionBarActivity and getSupportActionBar()

Comment: You are right, changing to ActionBarActivity and get SupportActionBar() resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are importing import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity , I guess you should use

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

instead of

```
getActionBar()
```

Comment: Because I want to run this on a earlier version of android (below 5.0) I decided to use getActionBar, which is where the problems begin

Comment: I guess this is the right answer. Did you try getSupportActionBar()?

Comment: getSupportActionBar() is available from API v7 (including v21)
getActionBar just started at v11 (including v21)

It's important which ActionBarActivity you are referencing in the Activity that displays the fragment.